# Multiple document picker or input type="file" Ionic v6 cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

This is a general question i am having regarding plugins my question is i can use

```
<input type="file" multiple/>
```

1. currently everything is working fine with input type="file"
2. Need to know if i face any issues that way
3. Any one implemented input type="file"?

in the same way i can also use multiple document picker plugin but only that i can't select the mime type but rest it works the same so i used input type="file" will i face any trouble because of using html element?

Comment: It will work fine, i have used it in my recent Projects. But it depends on your requirements as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code looks like this:

```
<input #fileInput multiple accept="" (change)="onFileChange($event)" type="file" name="file" id="file"
              class="inputfile">
```

Allows me to select any file type.

Comment: did you find any issue doing this way instead of using plugin

Comment: No issues, works fine, deployed and clients are satisfied with it.